# Spring Mvc passing model data to multiple pages before persisting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am in the process of creating a simple application with Spring Mvc and thymeleaf and I am currently thinking of what functionality I want to implement but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Let's say I have a model class Person. Regularly I have a form and a controller where I am passing the new person object and persist it with JPA.

No problem there but what if I want to have a page that I give some of the person basics info and then hit the "next" button and give some additional information. Then hit "next" again, review the data and hit "save"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by integrate **Spring Webflow** in your project.
Webflow is basically extensive part of WebMvc. Webflow has some configuration that, where you have to start and where you should go. If you have 5 page and you would like to all these data will put into database in one process then Webflow will help you. One more advantage is, you can add validation in particular pages and particular means you have five model and all these model will work in one flow. 
Read more, https://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Thymeleaf, but usually this kind of problem can be solved using some of the following methods or something similar:

1.) Save the unfinished data to database using the same schema or some other schema for this (or in session; in general sense, save it somewhere on server side). Problem with this is how to get rid of abandoned data where user has not moved to finish.

2.) Drag the data from page to page with request parameters. If the requests are of type POST then just in POST body, if they are type GET then as query parameters. Problem with this is it's not very clean.

3.) Don't do full page requests. Solve it with some front end solution using Javascript. Depending on the app it might or might not be possible.

4.) Do full page requests but still solve it in front end using local storage or session storage. Similar problems as with keeping the data in server side session.